# sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class '__builtin__.instance' is not mapped

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new to Python and still learning the basics. When running my program, it returns this error and I can't find the solution to this.

My codes are as follows:

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

...

class Illness:
    __tablename__ = "list_illnesses"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    illness = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, illness):
        self.illness = illness
```

```
import csv
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from models import *

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.getenv("DATABASE_URL")
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db.init_app(app)

def main():
    f = open("illnesses.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for name in reader:
        foo = Illness(illness=name[0])
        db.session.add(foo)
    db.session.commit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        main()
```

`illnesses.csv` only contains one illness name per line. I have been searching for hours but I can't seem to find the problem.

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: @IljaEverilä i think im using python 3

Answer (score 1):

It's probably significant that

class Illness:

isn't a subclass of `db.Model`.